# Is this antenna a LEGO piece?

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I came across this piece while sorting:

[image]

It appears to be similar to 2569, but it's clearly a different part. 2569 doesn't have the ridges and has a spherical tip rather than the cylindrical one on this part. The parts are roughly the same length.

[image: 2569]

I didn't see the word LEGO anywhere on the part, so I strongly suspect this is from a knockoff brand, but I wanted to make sure before I remove it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've never seen that part until now, and it's certainly not in the [antenna](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=1) or [bar](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=46) bricklink categories. I'm fairly confident it's not LEGO.

However, it would be far more interesting to know what it is, but that's not easy to search. A few Mega Bloks parts have been catalogued, but your part isn't there either (I could only check categories [bar](http://bloks.hyperboards.com/action/view_topic/topic_id/2085), [weapon](http://bloks.hyperboards.com/action/view_topic/topic_id/2113) and [tool/gear](http://bloks.hyperboards.com/action/view_topic/topic_id/2109) before I got sick, though). Considering that database is far from complete, it doesn't mean it's not Mega Bloks, though.

Actually, I think there's a good chance it IS Mega Blocks: the antennas on the [Repzyllian Trekker](http://en.bricker.ru/osets/MEGABLOKS/9311/) and the [Gyro Fighter](http://en.bricker.ru/osets/MEGABLOKS/9316/) look very much like yours.

Answer (score 7):

I have one and it is Mega Bloks. You can clearly tell the difference as Mega Bloks always appear lesser quality with slight ridge markings. I got mine from a bundle including Lego, Mega Bloks and COBI. But as Mega Bloks has very limited search facility there are no catalogue numbers